# Puncture resistant 18" tires?

Tags: tire, puncture

I need to replace the 18" cheap Schwalbe iMPAC Streetpac 47-355 tires that came with my Birdy folding bike with puncture resistante tires. I almost never ride on country roads, so thinner tires are fine.

Does someone know of alternatives to the Schwalbe Marathon Plus 35-355?

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with the Marathon Plus?

Comment: I don't know if there's anything wrong with the Schwalbe Maraton Plus, but I like to know my options when making a decision :)

Comment: Use a regular tire with Tuffy Tape.  I don't think they sell it for 18 inch tires, but as long as you get a width that fits your tire, you should be able to cut it to length, or even give yourself an extra layer of protection.

Comment: Worst case, you could always throw some tuffy liners inside tires that are not very puncture resistant.

Answer (score 1):

The Marathon Racer is also available in 18". Won't be as puncture resistant as the Plus, but lighter.

(My (second hand) Birdy is still on the Mad Mike's it came with. My previous folders (20" tyres) used Big Apples, and I didn't have puncture problems, and the Apple is also available in 18", but it's fatter.)

Comment: I had a chance to try a friend's Birdy with Marathon Racers. Definitely felt faster than mine - he could use a smaller sprocket on his hub gears (mine's an old Red, with derailleur).